# 100% CPU usage at idle, on Local machine when using a Remote kernel

Tags: linux, remote-access

I'm using a remote kernel for evaluations. But after I run a few cells, which include Importing some data, some equation solving and plotting (all of which uses the remote CPU), the Mathematica process on the local machine shoots up to ~100% CPU usage, and stays there till I kill it or close the program.

I'm using version 12.1, and am on the Linux kernel 5.6.2

The custom Shell command I'm using to launch the remote kernel:

```
ssh <user_name>@<ip_address> "/usr/bin/wolfram" -wstp -LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName "`linkname`"
```

How do I figure-out what is wrong?

Comment: Does the CPU use stay high if you scroll to some part of the notebook such that no graphics are shown? I've seen this in my 12.1 use when large/complex graphics is visible.

Comment: @ciao Yes, it does remain high even if I scroll away from plots. My plots are not very heavy anyway. Just a couple of lines made of lists of ~100 points.